# Create table in MySQL that matches another table?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL. I have a table called EMP, and now I need create one more table (EMP_TWO) with same schema, same columns, and same constraints. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried exporting the structure with something like phpMyAdmin and then just changing the table name?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

To create a new table based on another tables structure / constraints use :

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
```

To copy the data across, if required, use

```
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

[Create table docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html)

Beware of the notes on the LIKE option :

> Use LIKE to create an empty table based on the definition of another
>   table, including any column attributes and indexes defined in the
>   original table:
>
> CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE original_table; The copy is created using the same
>   version of the table storage format as the original table. The SELECT
>   privilege is required on the original table.
>
> LIKE works only for base tables, not for views.
>
> CREATE TABLE ... LIKE does not preserve any DATA DIRECTORY or INDEX
>   DIRECTORY table options that were specified for the original table, or
>   any foreign key definitions.

Comment: +1 Been using MySQL for years and was completely unaware that you could use `LIKE` in a `CREATE` statement.

Comment: @jprofitt I only know because I wanted to do this to test something on a production server (important query) the other day -> very useful !

Comment: @ManseUK what if i want to copy a table from one database and to re create it to another database?

Comment: In case someone needs the same table structure in another database, all you need to do is `CREATE TABLE new_db.new_table LIKE old_db.old_table` :)

Answer (score 22):

If you want to copy only Structure then use

```
create table new_tbl like old_tbl;
```

If you want to copy Structure as well as data then use

```
create table new_tbl select * from old_tbl;
```

Answer (score 9):

Create table in MySQL that matches another table?
Ans:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you go like this

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE Select * from Old_Table;
```

or You can go by filtering data like this

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE Select column1, column2, column3 from Old_Table where column1 = Value1;
```

For having Same constraint in your new table first you will have to create schema then you should go for data for schema creation

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE Some_other_Table;
```

Comment: Is it possible to use both `like` and `select *` in one statement? i am getting error. Also please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147565/create-table-like-a1-as-a2

Comment: I am not sure for mysql

Comment: Something similar is available for sqlserver that is 

select * into <NewTableName> from <OldTableName>;

Answer (score 0):

by only using the following command on MySQL command line 8.0 the following ERROR is displayed
[ mysql> select * into at from af;]

> ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: at

so just to copy the exact schema without the data in it you can use the create table with like statement as follows:

> create table EMP_TWO like EMP;

and to copy table along with the data use:

> create table EMP_TWO select * from EMP;

to only copy tables data after creating an empty table:

> insert into EMP_TWO select * from EMP;

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename
```

gives you the sql to recreate your table including indexes etc - just change the name to your desired new table name :)