# CREATE TABLE LIKE A1 as A2

Tags: mysql

I want to create a new table with properties of an old table and without duplicates. I want to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE New_Users  LIKE Old_Users, 
AS
(SELECT * FROM Old_Users GROUP BY ID) ;
```

But the above is not working.  Can anybody modify it to work?

Comment: Be aware that using `LIKE` will also make the new table have similar indexes.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Your attempt wasn't that bad. You have to do it with `LIKE`, yes.

In the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) it says:

> Use LIKE to create an empty table based on the definition of another
>   table, including any column attributes and indexes defined in the
>   original table.

So you do:

```
CREATE TABLE New_Users  LIKE Old_Users;
```

Then you insert with

```
INSERT INTO New_Users SELECT * FROM Old_Users GROUP BY ID;
```

But you can not do it in one statement.

Comment: the LIKE statement should be in parens: CREATE TABLE New_Users (LIKE Old_Users);

Comment: No, it's not necessary.

Comment: Just want to note that this does not copy Foreign Keys from the source table. I don't need them in my copy table, but someone else might.

Answer (score 4):

Based on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

What about:

```
Create Table New_Users Select * from Old_Users Where 1=2;
```

and if that doesn't work, just select a row and truncate after creation:

```
Create table New_Users select * from Old_Users Limit 1;
Truncate Table New_Users;
```

EDIT:

I noticed your comment below about needing indexes, etc. Try:

```
show create table old_users;
#copy the output ddl statement into a text editor and change the table name to new_users
#run the new query
insert into new_users(id,name...) select id,name,... form old_users group by id;
```

That should do it. It appears that you are doing this to get rid of duplicates? In which case you may want to put a unique index on id. if it's a primary key, this should already be in place. You can either:

```
#make primary key
alter table new_users add primary key (id);
#make unique
create unique index idx_new_users_id_uniq on new_users (id);
```

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, look through the link I posted in the answer, lots of examples in the mysql docs with no table specification. I can see it needing a specification for the 1st one to work as there is no data, but the 2nd example will work unless their docs are wrong.

Comment: I need new table to have same prorieties like old table

Comment: use the second example and then run "describe new_users;", what's different?

Comment: i tested now that I have a mysql instance available and both work

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL, you can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE New_Users   SELECT * FROM Old_Users group by ID;
```

Comment: Hi, yes it creating new table, but I need this new table to have same prorieties like old table.

Comment: Depend on mysql documantation you can't preserve indexes, PK's, etc. But you can define index like mysql documantation tells.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html
CREATE TABLE ... SELECT does not automatically create any indexes for you. This is done intentionally to make the statement as flexible as possible. If you want to have indexes in the created table, you should specify these before the SELECT statement:

mysql> CREATE TABLE bar (UNIQUE (n)) SELECT n FROM foo;

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;

or u can use this

CREATE TABLE new_table as
SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1 GROUP BY [column to remove duplicates by];

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to create table and insert distinct values into this table:

```
Select Distinct Column1, Column2, Column3 into New_Users from Old_Users
```