# Copy all columns without data but with dependencies in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

So i'm trying to copy all data of table CarOrders into a new table, NewCarOrders. But i only want to copy columns and dependencies and not data. I don't know if it truly matters, but i'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

Here are two things that i tried, but none worked.

```
SELECT *
INTO NewCarOrders
FROM CarOrders
WHERE 0 = 1
```

The issue with above is, it is copying all the columns but it is not copying the dependencies/relationships.
I saw some posts on some of the forums regarding this, but the suggested solution was using SSMS Wizard. I want to do it using SQL (or T-SQL).

I'm new to SQL world, so i'm really sorry if it is a stupid or no brainer question. Let me know if i am missing some important information, i'll update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query and check if this works for you

```
SELECT TOP 0 * 
INTO NewCarOrders
FROM CarOrders
```

This will create NewCarOrders table with same structure as CarOrders table and no rows in NewCarOrders.

```
SELECT * FROM NewCarOrders -- Returns zero rows
```

Note : This will not copy constraints , only structure is copied.
For constraints do as below -

1. In SSMS right click on the table CarOrders, Script Table As > Create To > New Query Window.
2. Change the name in the generated script to NewCarOrders and execute.

Also change the constraints name in the generated script else it will throw error like *There is already an object named 'xyz' in the  database*

Comment: is this will copy all the dependencies/relationships also?

Comment: Hi Mudassir, so i tried that query but i'm getting error in syntax. INTO is red marked, and it says, "Incorrect syntax near "INTO", expecting '.', ID or QUOTED_ID."

Comment: OP already know how to copy schema, concern is about relation.

Comment: check now .....

Comment: Okay i did as you said, i replaced all "CarOrders" in script with "NewCarOrders", but i'm getting a lot of errors. "Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 11
There is already an object named 'NewCarOrders' in the database."

Comment: you have to do either one of them .. i think you have executed the `SELECT * INTO` query and then doing from SSMS. Drop the `NewCarOrders` table. then do the steps as listed in second solution i.e. from SSMS.

Comment: It worked :) Thanks a lot Mudassir. You were right, i did both of those things, hence the error. But i dropped the table, and replaced the name in the script, and it worked. Thank you. :)

Comment: Btw this is totally different question, so feel free to ask me to delete this. Whenever i create a table, and use SELECT statement once on it, and i try to drop it, i always get this error "Cannot drop the table 'dbo.NewCarOrders', because it does not exist or you do not have permission"  I mean the table clearly exists, so what is up with permissions?

Comment: This answer also uses SSMS. There is a pure t-sql solution in the answers of the duplicate question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Can you please give a link to that question? Apologies for duplicate question. Thanks :)

Comment: @Shrey You already have a link - on the top of your question with a yellow background.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `like` command:

```
CREATE TABLE  NewCarOrders LIKE CarOrders;
```

Comment: No, that will generate a syntax error.

Comment: @JasonAller why bother editing an answer that is so clearly wrong, and on a duplicate question?

Comment: for points.. :D

Comment: @GeomanYabes once you get to 2000 reputation, you get the [Edit Questions And Answers Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Your edits are automatically approved but you no longer get the 2 reputation points for approved edits, so that can't be it.

Comment: @JasonAller without completely changing the answer, it can't be improved. Formatting is great but it can't replace the wrong content...

Comment: Could it have been an attempt at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147565/create-table-like-a1-as-a2