# Creating non-empty table while preserving index in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create a copy of an original table (non-empty) while preserving index using LIKE? This is what I have so far but it giving me a "SELECT is not valid at this position" error.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_copy LIKE my_table
SELECT *
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Answer can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147565/create-table-like-a1-as-a2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either want:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_copy LIKE my_table;

INSERT INTO my_table_copy
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table;
```

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_copy as
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table;
```

The primary difference is that `LIKE` also creates indexes.