# MySQL query to identify near duplicate matches with specific pattern, update child table

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Due to a badly parsed .csv `LOAD DATA INFILE` routine, I now have rows in the unique `host.name` field with nearly duplicate values, differing only that one set leads with a carriage return (0A). `host.id` in all the correct rows is `<100` and conversely `host.id` in all incorrect rows is `>100`.

That's simple to correct of course, but I also now have incorrectly linked data in `host_metric` from updates that joined the incorrect near duplicates with `host.id = host_metric.host_id`

So, I need to update `host_metric.host_id` with the correct `host.id` value first. I was thinking of solving by joining the `host` table on itself by making the nearly duplicate `host.name` duplicate, and updating `host_metric.host_id` with `a.id`, but I'm getting tangled up.

```
UPDATE host_metric c
SET c.host_id = (SELECT a.id
  FROM host a
  INNER JOIN host b ON concat("0A", hex(a.name)) = hex(b.name)
  WHERE a.id <> b.id
  AND a.id < '100'
  AND b.id > '100')
INNER JOIN host d ON c.host_id = d.id;
```

How can I correctly phrase this query?

EDIT: Here's some sample data:

Here's some sample near duplicate rows from `host` table (146 is incorrect):

```
MySQL [vmr]> select id, name from host where name like "%d60server10%";
+-----+--------------------------+
| id  | name                     |
+-----+--------------------------+
|   1 | d60server10.domain  |
| 146 |
d60server10.domain |
+-----+--------------------------+
```

Here's a correct entry in `host_metric` with the correct `host_id`:

```
MySQL [vmr]> select * from host_metric where host_id='1' limit 1;
+---------+-----------+---------------------+-------+
| host_id | metric_id | metric_ts           | value |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+-------+
|       1 |         1 | 2016-06-08 06:30:00 |  1.23 |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+-------+
```

Here's an incorrect entry in `host_metric`, linked from almost-duplicate row in `host`:

```
MySQL [vmr]> select * from host_metric where host_id='146' limit 1;
+---------+-----------+---------------------+-------+
| host_id | metric_id | metric_ts           | value |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+-------+
|     146 |         1 | 2016-06-07 06:30:00 |  0.57 |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+-------+
```

So in this example data, I need to update all rows in `host_metric` where `host_id = 146' to '1'.

Comment: I'm also getting tangled up.  Please show brief, but representative, sample data showing the state of the tables and what your desired output is.

Comment: if you can show some sample data it will help others to provide a solution

Comment: Example data has been added; apologies that it wasn't included initially. Thanks.

Comment: copy the tables to backups before you foobar them more. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8761381

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs across anything similar, I was able to repair this (I believe) by breaking it down a little bit and using a temporary table.

Beforehand I ran: `SELECT host_id,count(host_id) FROM host_metric GROUP BY host_id;` to get a total count of each id. After step #5 below, I re-ran this and the correct ID counts reflected the addition of the merged incorrect ids.

1. Create temp table

`CREATE TABLE host_tmp LIKE host;`

2. Copy over the problematic near duplicate rows to temp table from original:

`INSERT INTO host_tmp SELECT * FROM HOST WHERE id > '100';`

3. Remove hidden characters in name field in host_tmp so we can join with it:

`UPDATE host_tmp SET name = replace(name,'\r','');`
`UPDATE host_tmp SET name = replace(name,'\n','');`

4. Add a column to the temp table to match the original (correct) ids:

`ALTER TABLE host_tmp ADD ido int(4);`

5. Populate the original (correct) ids from host so we have an index:

   `UPDATE host_tmp t
   INNER JOIN host h ON t.name = h.name
   SET t.ido = h.id
   WHERE t.id > 100;`
6. Update the host_metric (child) table so to correct the host_ids:

   `UPDATE host_metric m 
    INNER JOIN host_tmp t ON t.id = m.host_id
    SET m.host_id = t.ido
    WHERE m.host_id > '100';`
7. Remove the (incorrect) almost duplicate rows from host:

`DELETE FROM host where id > '100';`

8. Finally, remove the temporary table:

`DROP table host_tmp;`